# fatal error: opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp' file not found (open cv already built)

Tags: c++, opencv, include

I have downloaded and built open cv according to these [open cv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).

I am trying to compile this [Eigenfaces demo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html), and I am getting the following error.

```
fatal error: 'opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp' file not found
```

The line of concern is

```
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
```

The contrib directory is not in my `usr/local/include/opencv/` directory. I have referenced the following [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222067/mac-osx-build-opencv-contrib-fatal-error-file-not-found-opencv2-core-hpp), but it seems to only handle the case of building from scratch.

Also, the repository that it references [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) does not even contain the file `contrib.hpp`

How can I simply add the necessary source files to my current build without having to completely rebuild everything?

Comment: Also, I know that if the file was in the include directory I would have to change the path, but it still was not there anyways.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're obviously using opencv3.0:

the contrib parts have been outsourced to a [separate github repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib)

You'll have to get that, append it to your main opencv (re-)build, and then:

```
   #include <opencv2/face.hpp>
   using namespace cv;
   Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> model = face::createLBPHFaceRecognizer(...)
```

(an additional namespace was added here)

Comment: Is there no way to add this functionality to my current build?

Comment: Thanks, can you add instructions for this re-build to your answer? I think it will help my self and the SO community

Comment: hmm, try the [instructions](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) , and come back, when (and where) it did not work for you ?

Comment: The build worked. However, now I am receiving errors similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863538/no-member-named-getmat-in-cvfacefacerecognizer

Comment: please make sure to use the updated sample code from opencv_contrib, not something older you found on SO or such.