# error: no member named 'getMat' in 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer'

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, opencv3.0

I am using `opencv-3.0`, to implement this [opencv facial recognition demo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) from the opencv docs.

I believe this demo was written using `opencv-2.4`. However, I have added the `contrib` src to my build, as was advised in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806834/fatal-error-opencv2-contrib-contrib-hpp-file-not-found-open-cv-already-built/29806967?noredirect=1#comment47742059_29806967).

However, I now receive the following error:

```
error: no member named 'getMat' in 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer'
```

The offending code is

```
Mat eigenvalues = model->FaceRecognizer::getMat("eigenvalues");
```

I am compiling my code like so

```
g++ -o facerec_demo facerec_demo.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Is there a way to fix this, or is this demo completely incompatible with `opencv-3.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/face/doc/facerec_tutorial.html), the `model` in the following line is a *pointer* to a `FaceRecognizer` class instance, instead of the object itself.

```
129:    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
        ...
143:    Mat eigenvalues = model->getMat("eigenvalues");
```

Thus, it makes sense that the `getMat` function is not defined in `FaceRecognizer` class, but it should be defined for `Ptr<FaceRecognizer>`.

Comment: careful, above answer is **only** valid for the now **obsolete rc3.0** version, api has changed [again](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/dc/dd7/classcv_1_1face_1_1BasicFaceRecognizer.html#ab34eeaa66965821c0593e03ffe1d3a74)  (the docs cited above are outdated, too) . please also take a look at the updated [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/da/d60/tutorial_face_main.html)