# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"cv::face::createFisherFaceRecognizer(int, double)", referenced from: _main in main.o

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am working on facial recognition in video using opencv. I followed the tutorial on opencv's website(http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html). I get following error when I try to build my code in xcode.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::face::createFisherFaceRecognizer(int, double)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

I made a few changes to the code as given in here [fatal error: opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp' file not found (open cv already built)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806834/fatal-error-opencv2-contrib-contrib-hpp-file-not-found-open-cv-already-built/29806967#29806967)

Please guide me through it as I am new to opencv.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, the error states that you are compiling your (client) code for x86_64 but OpenCV is compiled for x86.

Comment: Oh! how do I rectify it ?

Comment: Are you actually linking with cv library? Showing linker command will help. Also please ensure that your opencv library is built for x86_64.

Comment: I followed this tutorial to setup opencv-3.0 with xcode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJeP1juuHHY and I used following linker flag : The default location of the header files is: /usr/local/include
The default location of the library files is : /usr/local/lib
The additional linker flags are: -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab

Comment: Both OpenCV and your code must be built for the same target architecture; the architecture of a (dynamic linked) binary (`.so` or an exceutable) can be checked (among others) running `file` upon it. You can check OpenCV so file(s) that way.I don't know how you got OpenCV (downloaded the binaries or compiled it yourself), but the easiest way would be to build your code for x86 (to get it working), and then switch all to x86_64 (to benefit of its advantages).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am trying to follow your suggestion.

Comment: `-lopencv_face` is missing from the libs list

Comment: Thank you so much Berak! adding -lopencv_face solved my problem:):)